# how to get this twist geometry to start and end at same points as the Bezier curve

Tags: edit-mode, bezier-curves

I have created some twist geometry using the simple deform tool and now I would like it to follow the Bezier curve from start to finish. However, it seems to overhand on one end of the Bezier curve and shortened on the other end. Is there a setting I am missing? Thanks

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: can you provide blend file pls?

Comment: done. I plan to mirror this to the other side to form a heart.

Comment: @user9106985, I've edited, as Nathan says you can enable both Stretch and Bounds Clamp to make the object begin and end at the curve extremities

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apply the *Scale* and *Rotation* of both the 2 objects, bring back the vertex radius of the curve back to 1 (in *Edit* mode: right click > *Set Curve Radius* > 1). Set the origin of both object to their geometry and put them both at the same location. To make the object begin at the curve beginning and end at its end, you can enable *Stretch* and *Bounds Clamp*:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Many thanks for this. I will try it in the next few days!

Comment: That works. Thanks!